# How to enable mod_rewrite in winginx server

Tags: winginx

I've installed winginx server in my windows xp system, I've created a wordpress site, which works perfectly fine, but the main issue is wordpress permalinks are not working.

I've browsed various sites regarding this issue. But I'm unable to solve it.

Pls help me in resolving this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Winginx Workbench > Server Config >

```
server {
listen 127.0.0.1:80;
server_name yoursitename.com www.yoursitename.com;

root home/yoursitename/public_html;

index index.php index.html;

log_not_found off;
access_log logs/yoursitename-access.log;

charset utf-8;



location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$request_uri;
}



location ~ /\. { deny all; }
location = /favicon.ico { }
location = /robots.txt { }

location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
}

}
```